# TextView showing only one character when gravity style is applied

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a table with 3 rows of numbers (summary information). When the TextViews are styled with their default gravity, the text shows correctly.

[image]

But when they're styled with `<item name="android:gravity">right</item>`, each TextView shows only the first character of what it should.

[image]

This even includes the column headers - not shown here - which I'm not even changing.

I would like the table values to be right-aligned to be consistent with the rest of the app and I'm stumped as to why the values in the table would be behaving like this.

Here's my style (for when it doesn't work):

```
<style name="summary_values">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_size</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
</style>
```

Here's the XML for one of the cells (they're all basically the same)

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/value1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="@integer/table_weight_percent_value"
    style="@style/summary_values"/>
```

**Edit**

The truncating happens even when the `gravity` is set to `left` or `center`.

**Edit 2**

I've removed the `<item name="android:gravity">right</item>` line from the style altogether and it's still truncating sometimes, depending on the values. I've stepped through my code and the values in the code are correct.

**Edit 3**

After removing all styling except the font colour, the truncating still happens, but I haven't figured out when. If I change numbers in the input table, the summary values are sometimes truncated and sometimes not.

Here is a row from the table. All the rows are similar, apart from id changes.

```
<TableRow
    android:padding="@dimen/pad_12">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/table_weight_percent_label"
        android:text="@string/cho"
        style="@style/label_light"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/percent_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/table_weight_percent_value"
        style="@style/summary_values"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/val1a"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/table_weight_percent_value"
        style="@style/summary_values"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/val1b"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/table_weight_percent_value"
        style="@style/summary_values"/>
</TableRow>
```

**Edit 4**

After trying a number of things, I changed the containing `TableView` to a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation. I even left the `TableRow` views as they were (just adding in layout_width and layout_height). Amazingly, it works now.

To describe the odd behaviour a little more: when it was showing only the first character, if I opened the soft keyboard and closed it again, the table would display correctly, until I changed one of the EditText values. It still behaved in this strange manner even when I removed 2 of the columns from the table, so there was plenty of space for the views.

Comment: Does it do that with any value you set to `android:gravity`?  Like, does it truncate with `left` or `center`?

Comment: @AndrewSchuster: Just tried it and yes, it does truncate with `left` and `center`.

Comment: When you dump the view hierarchy, are the text views in correct position and with wrong size, or in the wrong position with correct size?

Comment: @matiash: I haven't done that before and it's taking me a while to get it right.

Comment: I asked because it would seem probable that all the TextViews are bigger than they should horizontally, and overlapping one another. When the text is left-aligned inside it's not visible, but it is when the text is at the center or right. What is the value of table_weight_percent_value? Am I making sense? :)

Comment: You are making sense, except that when the TextViews have their gravity set to `left`, it is still truncating the text. I've just managed to do the hierarchy dump and all my views are correctly sized and positioned

Comment: "Correctly sized" meaning they occupy the full column space? Well, that's strange. Could you build a standalone example reproducing this problem?

Comment: can you post your xml containing the table and textviews

Comment: Do your "summary_values" style have any parent?

Comment: Nope. I pasted the whole style

Comment: Could not reproduce your problem. Could you post the complete code (layouts, strings, dimens) or simplify yours to make it possible to assemble exactly the same example?

Comment: Can you please mail me you project ?

Comment: Project Clean, Restart Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying a number of things, I changed the containing TableView to a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. I even left the TableRow views as they were (just adding in layout_width and layout_height). Amazingly, it works now.

I have no idea why it didn't work or why it works now. I'd really appreciate if anyone could give some insight into it.